# How to generate Audio Spectrum when you play audio file from remote url?

Tags: android, fft, audio-streaming, spectrum

I have one screen in which i have created my custom audio player where i play the audio file which received from the webservice.I am successfully done this part. Now , as per the audio file i want to generate an audio spectrum of that audio file. I have searched over the net and found some library related FFT. But i don't know how to integrate it in my code so i needed some example or guidance that how to implement it ?

Any help would be appreciated :-)

Thanks in Advance .....

Answer (score 0):

apple has a sample app with full source code called :  aurioTouch
which has a nice FFT display

Comment: AurioTorch is only for microphone. From iOS6 it is possible easy for other ones.